# Como fazer update vários registros php postgresql?

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql

Preciso de atualizar vários registros ao mesmo tempo com php/postgresql (também serve para mysql) através de um checkbox e textbox mas não estou a conseguir.
O código abaixo só atualiza o campo sequencia do último registro e não atualiza o status. Os restantes registros, nada é atualizado.
O meu código:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="form" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
<div style="overflow-y:scroll; width:100%; height:90%;">
<?php
$query = pg_query($dbconn,"select *, case when idstatus = 1 then 'checked=\"checked\"' else '' end as status1 from tabela") or die(pg_last_error($dbconn));
?>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="20" cellpadding="0" align="center">
  <tr>
    <?php
    $loop = 3;
    $i = 1;
    while($queryRow = pg_fetch_array($query)){        
      if($i < $loop){
              echo '
              <td valign="middle" align="center">                                         
              <img src="imagem/'.$queryRow['imagem'].'" width="250" height="150" /><br />
              <p>
              <table width="250" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                  <td align="right" valign="middle" width="33%">STATUS</td>
                  <td style="padding:5px;" align="left" valign="middle" width="33%"><input name="status" type="checkbox" value=1" '.$queryRow ['status1'].' /></td>
                  <td style="padding:5px;" align="center" valign="middle" width="34%"><input name="sequencia" type="text" value="'.$queryRow['sequencia'].'" /><input name="id" type="hidden" value="'.$queryRow['id'].'" /></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              </p>              
              </td>
              ';
      }elseif($i = $loop){                    
              echo '                                            
              <td valign="middle" align="center">                                         
              <img src="imagem/'.$queryRow['imagem'].'" width="250" height="150" /><br />
              <p>
              <table width="250" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                  <td align="right" valign="middle" width="33%">STATUS</td>
                  <td style="padding:5px;" align="left" valign="middle" width="33%"><input name="status" type="checkbox" value=1" '.$queryRow ['status1'].' /></td>
                  <td style="padding:5px;" align="center" valign="middle" width="34%"><input name="sequencia" type="text" value="'.$queryRow['sequencia'].'" /><input name="id" type="hidden" value="'.$queryRow['id'].'" /></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              </p>              
              </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              </p>  
              </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
              ';
      $i = 0;
      }
    $i++;
    }
    ?>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div style="width:100%; height:10%; background:none;">
<table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0" style="border-top:#000099 solid 3px;">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="middle"><button>ATUALIZAR</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>    
</div>
<?php
if(isset($_POST)){
    $count = count($_POST['id']); 
    $i = 0; 

    while ($i < $count) { 
        $id = $_POST['id'][$i]; 
        $status = $_POST['status'][$i];
        $sequencia = $_POST['sequencia'][$i]; 

        $query = pg_query($dbconn,"update tabela set status = $status, sequencia = $sequencia where id = $id") or die(pg_last_error($dbconn));
        echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=index.php">';
        ++$i; 
    }
}           
?> 
</form>
```

Comment: complementei a pergunta: O código abaixo só atualiza o campo sequencia do último registro e não atualiza o status. Os restantes registros, nada é atualizado.

Comment: não entendi o negativo, o iluminado pode explicar?